# trying to use animation zoom out on background image using but its not correct

Tags: html, css, css-animations

[This is my demo link](http://www.hitendratomar.in/demo/)

and here is the reference link what i want

[reference link](https://www.mentorsonly.com/)

when i am trying to zoom out that background images using animation in my css

after end of animation its look like a cut 
and one more thing is that mouse hover effect i want to use that also. Please check and help me out if you can

Comment: Your demo link is not working. Please add a bare minimum of code working example.

Comment: @alljamin please check now

Comment: @alljamin i edited the link you can check now

Comment: I do not see a working (faulty) code example of your problem. Please add it.  This how you can do this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51144/how-do-i-post-code-in-stackoverflow